# How do I display the first five numbers on a single line and the second five numbers on another line?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create a do-while loop, counting from 1 to 10, that displays the first five numbers on the first line and the next five numbers on another line.
But whenever I run my code, the 6th iteration and onward print on seperate lines each instead of the same line.
If anyone could help me understand the error that I made and how to corret it, I would appreciate it.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello_World {  // Declare Class
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    // Main Method
        
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");  // Decimal_Format!
        
        /*
         * While Loop count from 1 to 10
         */
        
        int x = 1;  // Declare and Initialize variable 'X'
        do 
        {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
            x++;
            
            if (x > 5) {
                System.out.println("");
                continue;
            }
            
        }
        while (x <= 10);
        }
        
    }   // Braces delimit blocks of code!
```

Comment: if ( x == 5) ...  remove continue

Comment: Well, what does `if (x > 5) {` do when `x == 6`? When `x == 7`? When `x == 8`? Do you see why this causes a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You only want to print the newline when `x` is `6`. Also, you could use `printf` to make this a bit cleaner. Something like,

```
int x = 1; // Declare and Initialize variable 'X'
do {
    if (x == 6) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.printf("%3d ", x);
    x++;
} while (x <= 10);
```

Outputs

```
  1   2   3   4   5 
  6   7   8   9  10
```

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is with your if-statement

[image]

By setting the if statement to be true if x > 5 it will trigger for 6 through 10 which is why you get your numbers above 5 all on a separate line. If you just set the new line to kick in when x == 6 it will only trigger a new line when x is 6 and in no other circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a two-loop solution.  The outer loop increments through the entire range you want; the inner loop increments through a single line.

```
int limit = 10;
int perLine = 5;
for (int x = 1; x <= limit; x += perLine) {
    for (int y = x; y < x + perLine && y <= limit; y++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", y);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This solution works even if the 'limit' is not an exact multiple of 'perLine'.

I wrote this with a for-loop out of sheer habit, but you could convert it to do-while easily enough.

```
int limit = 10;
int perLine = 5;
int x = 1;
do {
    int y = x;
    do {
         System.out.printf("%3d", y);
         y++;
    } while (y < x + perLine && y <= limit);
    System.out.println();
    x += perLine;
} while (x <= limit);
```

However, it's a lot more long-winded that way, so unless this is being done as an exercise in using do-while, I'd use a for-loop.